# back/front filling values in SQL

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have table in PrestoSQL that looks like this:

```
 test
    id value           timestamp
1  foo  blue 2019-10-17 17:42:52
2  foo  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:43:52
3  foo  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:44:52
4  foo   red 2019-10-17 17:45:52
5  foo  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:46:52
6  bar  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:47:52
7  bar green 2019-10-17 17:48:52
8  bar  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:49:52
9  bar  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:50:52
10 bar  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:51:52
```

My objective is to fill in the values after they appear in `value` for example:

```
 output
    id value           timestamp
1  foo  blue 2019-10-17 17:42:52
2  foo  blue 2019-10-17 17:43:52
3  foo  blue 2019-10-17 17:44:52
4  foo   red 2019-10-17 17:45:52
5  foo   red 2019-10-17 17:46:52
6  bar  <NA> 2019-10-17 17:47:52
7  bar green 2019-10-17 17:48:52
8  bar green 2019-10-17 17:49:52
9  bar green 2019-10-17 17:50:52
10 bar green 2019-10-17 17:51:52
```

I understand how to use `lead()` and `lag()`, but how would one write a query to fill in current values from the previous known value by timestamp (and id) if it is not NA ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`lag()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#lag) with [`IGNORE NULLS`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#value-functions). Example:

```
presto:default> SELECT
             ->   a, t, v,
             ->   coalesce(v, lag(v, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY t))
             -> FROM (VALUES
             ->   ('a', 1, 'red'),
             ->   ('a', 2, NULL),
             ->   ('a', 3, 'blue'),
             ->   ('a', 4, NULL),
             ->   ('a', 5, NULL)
             -> ) t(a, t, v);
             ->
 a | t |  v   | _col3
---+---+------+-------
 a | 1 | red  | red
 a | 2 | NULL | red
 a | 3 | blue | blue
 a | 4 | NULL | blue
 a | 5 | NULL | blue
(5 rows)
```

(tested in Presto 322)

Comment: it's not an option in PrestoSQL

Comment: It is. Updated the answer now with a working example.